# Why does using a list as a string formatting parameter, even with no %s identifier, return the original string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
>>> 'string with no string formatting markers' % ['string']
'string with no string formatting markers'
>>> 'string with no string formatting markers' % ('string',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I would expect both cases to raise a `TypeError`, but this is not the case. Why not?

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) on this subject talks about strings, tuples and dictionaries, but says nothing about lists. I'm a bit confused about this behavior. I've been able to duplicate it in Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Comment: Looks like an undocumented "feature" (bug) to me.

Comment: FWIW, `jython2.2.1` *does* raise a `TypeError`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading carefully, the documentation states that:

> If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-`tuple`
>   object. Otherwise, values must be a `tuple` with exactly the number
>   of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object
>   (for example, a dictionary).

Now, in this case the `format` does not require a single argument and thus the documentation tells us that you should use a `tuple` or a mapping as argument; other cases fall in "undefined behaviour"(which is what is happening: the behaviour is not consistent in all cases).

This should probably be considered the final answer to the question: if the string does not have any format specifier, using a `list`(or any kind different from `tuple` or a mapping) should simply be considered a bug by itself leading to undefined behaviour.

From this follows that you ought to **always** use a `tuple` or `dict` as argument, otherwise you have to check for format specifiers by hand or handle odd behaviours.

In your case you can probably fix the problem using `(['string'], )` instead of `['string']`.

---

Possible "explanation" of why the resultant behaviour seems to be so random:

It seems like there was a buggy [check](http://bugs.python.org/issue6396#msg90009) in the original implementation of `PyString_Format`/`PyUnicode_Format`, instead of using `PyMappingCheck` on [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a9341ce35abc/Objects/stringobject.c#l4257) line:

```
if (PyMapping_Check(args) && !PyTuple_Check(args) &&
     !PyObject_TypeCheck(args, &PyBaseString_Type))
    dict = args;
```

It was used this code:

```
if (Py_TYPE(args)->tp_as_mapping && !PyTuple_Check(args) &&
    !PyObject_TypeCheck(args, &PyBaseString_Type))
    dict = args;
```

which is not equivalent. For example `set` does not have `tp_as_mapping` set(at least in the Python2.7.3 source code that I have downloaded some weeks ago), while `list` does set it.

This might be the reason why `list`(and possibly other objects) do not raise the `TypeError` while, `set`, `int` and many others do.

As I stated before in this same answer I do get `TypeError` even with `list`s:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'some string' % []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This probably shows that the above issue is not the only one here.

Looking at the source code I agree that, *in theory*, the number of arguments is not checked if the argument is not a tuple, but this would imply `'some string' % 5 -> 'some string'` and not a `TypeError`, so there must be something fishy in that code.

Comment: What version of python 2 are you trying? I can't reproduce that on 2.5.4, 2.6.1 or 2.7.2

Comment: That's interesting, it raises a `TypeError` for you in Python 2? It doesn't for me:

`Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'some string' % ['a']
'some string'`

Comment: I don't get the `TypeError` that you're showing (and from the question, I don't think OP is either) i.e. `"foobar"%['duck']` happily returns `"foobar"`.  I'm using Python2.7.3, 2.6.4, 3.2.3 on OS-X 10.5.8 ... No error with python2.7.3, 2.6.5, 3.2.0 on Ubuntu