# Escape sequence for % character

Tags: python, escaping

I have a following code which works fine.

```
a = 5
b = "%"
print "Hello %d \%s" % (a ,b)
```

Output:

```
$ python a.py
Hello 5 \%
```

But if i try to write code in this way

```
a = 5
print "Hello %d \%" % a
```

It is giving error, it seems escape sequence in not working for '%'

```
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    print "Hello %d \%" % a
ValueError: incomplete format
```

To be more accurrate, it thier is any way to enter '%' character in 2nd programm.

Comment: Note that `%`-formatting has some [corner cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13864532/510937) that can give surprising results. You should use `str.format` instead, which is a bit safer from this point of view. In particular if you use more than one format in the string you *must* use either a *tuple* with the values, or a *mapping*. Using any other object (even a `list`) is "undefined behaviour" (see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)) which ranges from giving the expected output to raising an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [new-style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
print "Hello {} %".format(a)
```

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting in new code.

Or a double `%`:

```
print "Hello %d %%" % a
```

Comment: And to escape `'{'` and `'}'` inside new-style formatting the same trick applies: `'{{'.format() == '{'`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called format escaping.

```
>>> print 'hello %s %%' % 5
hello 5 %
```

You just need to use 2 %.

[Documentation:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

> '%%'  No argument is converted, results in a '%' character in the
>   result.

Answer (score 0):

When you use string formatting (`"some %s" % ('string')`), the `%` character has to be escaped. To do that, just use `%%`.

If you string is not formatted, you don't have to do that.

See [this guide](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) on string formatting.