# Why does Python string formatting silently ignore mismatched argument counts with class instances?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Normally, Python old-style string formatting complains if the number of placeholders in the string doesn't match the number of arguments passed:

```
>>> 'no.placeholders.here' % 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

However, when the argument passed is an instance of a user-defined class, it instead silently ignores it:

```
>>> class Test(object): pass
>>> 'no.placeholders.here' % Test()
'no.placeholders.here'
```

This behavior seems inconsistent and has resulted in some difficult-to-track-down bugs. Why does the type of the format argument matter for the purposes of this error?

Comment: I have tried your examples and for me throws the same TypeError for both cases. Are you sure it ignores silently the second case? What version of python are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior in Python 2.6. Appears to be a bug in that version of Python; Python 2.7 behaves as expected.

Comment: I should note, I was able to reproduce the behavior with instances of any old user-defined class, not just Django classes. Even `class myclass: pass`. Then `"foo" % myclass()` returns `"foo"` instead of an error. That's why I say it's a bug in Python. `"foo" % object()` is an error, however.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3, and it does trigger the silent ignore behavior with any instance of a user-defined class as kindall pointed out. I also tested 2.7.5 and it did the same thing. Which version behaved as expected @kindall?

Comment: I edited the question to remove the red herring of Django model instances.

Comment: I believe pylint catches these errors, so maybe it might be more reliable than python implementation for catching this.

Comment: Python 2.7 string `__mod__` operator: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Objects/stringobject.c#l3743

`PyString_Format()`: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Objects/stringobject.c#l4231 ... looks one big hairy function and no comments :(

Comment: The version of Python 2.7 that I didn't see the bug with was Python 2.7.5, so it's odd that @user686782 saw it there! Maybe a platform difference...? (Windows here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is exactly why `%`-formatting is *old***

`%`-formatting is *well known* for its inconsistencies about argument handling which result in exceptions or not depending on the type. There are only two ways to use `%` formatting and avoid inconsistencies:

1. Make sure the formatting string contains *exactly* one formatting field and pass the object to format as only right argument
2. Use a `tuple` or `dict` as right argument. Don't use `list`s, `set`s or `Model`s. **Only** `tuple`s and `dicts`.

These are taken from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

> If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple
>   object. Otherwise, values **must** be a tuple with exactly the number
>   of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object
>   (for example, a dictionary).

Your examples do not fall in these two cases because you have 0 formatting fields, which is different than 1 and thus the right argument **must** be a `tuple` or a mapping, but you are passing a string and a user defined object. As such you are under "undefined behaviour".

The inconsistencies on the error messages were already discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13864532/510937) question (in my answer).

If you want more consistent behaviour, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Perfect explanation: thanks! I guess it "makes sense" in the same way as how `{} + [] == 0` in JS: perfectly specified but really confusing.